# Fitting long text on app

Tags: ios, user-interface, cocoa-touch

On my application I have a menu button that drops downs different categories to use. One category is called "books, music, games and movies" however on as it is too big it goes off the screen. What is the best practice for me to keep this category name but adapt the size of the text?

Answer (score 1):

Without much context, I would say to set a trailingEdge constraint to your UILabels/whatever you are using to hold your categories text to be 8 points from the view's trailing edge.  Then (if you are using UILabels) set the label's lines number == 0, and line break mode to word wrap.  You can also set the label's AutoShrink to allow the text's font to shrink to fit the label if it needs to.

The constraint doesn't have to be 8 points, set that to whatever you want, but make sure it is set so that the label's trailing edge is contained inside the parentView.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an issue with the font sizes being different you could set the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property on the UILabel to true and that will auto size the text to fit in the width. Otherwise you could start by replacing the `and` with `&` or showing the name on multiple lines in the `UILabel`. Another solution would be to give the drop down menu more width.